# Rails 3 associations. migration for a HABTM with a more than one word model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm creating a HABTM association between line_items and taxes.

What would the name of the association table be called? line_items_taxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails expects that the Join Table is named "alphabetically":

As such, it would be called `line_items_taxes`. You can override this behavior in the model.